# Simple udev rule does not work

Tags: udev

whats wrong with this simple udev rule?

```
KERNEL=="sdc1", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir /tmp/folder1"
```

When I plug in my USB-Stick the rule does nothing.

Comment: Your stick isn't `sdc1`?

Comment: shure, it is sdc / sdc1

Answer (score 0):

No, you may not able to create folder.

Because `sd??` nodes are created by kernel before the partition get mounted.

Better to look for a different approach, example using a script with `udisks`.

Answer (score -1):

Use a rule with UUID matching:

```
KERNEL=="sd??", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="<the_uuid>", RUN+="/bin/mkdir /tmp/folder1"
```

get the UUID with the command below

```
udevadm info /dev/<usb_stick_partition> | grep ID_FS_UUID=
```

*Example*

```
$ udevadm info /dev/sda1 | grep ID_FS_UUID=
E: ID_FS_UUID=c44a008d-58b2-467d-8814-f06973e49dcb
```

therefore

```
KERNEL=="sd??", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="c44a008d-58b2-467d-8814-f06973e49dcb", RUN+="/bin/mkdir /tmp/folder1"
```

Comment: Is it possible to add at least terse hints on how you actually use this? Link to more info?